# Is p-bromophenol more acidic than p-chlorophenol?

Tags: acid-base, orbitals, molecular-orbital-theory

*p*-chlorophenol is more acidic than *p*-fluorophenol due to presence of vacant d orbitals. But then is *p*-bromophenol more acidic than *p*-chlorophenol since it has vacant f orbitals also? But I guess that’s wrong, isn’t it? Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: This is not necessarily the "correct" answer as many factors play roles and it would be difficult to describe the observation so simply.

I'm not sure I can provide an easily "correct" answer, but I can try to explain some of the many factors that influence the acidity.

Most notably, the factors we should consider are inductive effects and delocalization of charge.

The inductive effects, based on electronegativity, would dismiss the experimental observation, so I'll look at delocalization of charge.

The delocalization of charge, which introduces a negative charge by the halogen is greatest by F>Cl>Br>I. This would reduce acidity, as a more negative benzene ring would not desire to gain another negative charge. Thus, this is one factor that supports the experimental observation.

Thus, we may be able to explain the observation, if only partially, by the delocalization of charge.

I adapted the answer to a similar question on http://www.quora.com/Organic-Chemistry/Which-is-more-acidic-ortho-fluorophenol-ortho-chlorophenol-ortho-bromophenol-or-ortho-iodophenol-Why . I would have preferred more sources but I could not find a very good source.

Comment: Experimental data provides the correct answer: [4-bromophenol](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/4-bromophenol#section=Chemical-and-Physical-Properties) (pKa = 9.17) is a stronger acid than [4-chlorophenol](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/4-chlorophenol#section=Chemical-and-Physical-Properties) (pKa = 9.41). Scroll down to "dissociation constant". References are provided.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up the pKa values of each chloro- and bromophenol and compiled them in the following little table:

| pKa | chlorophenol | bromophenol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ortho- | 8.49 | 8.45 |
| meta- | 8.81 | 9.03 |
| para- | 9.14 | 9.17 |

(These are just the first values that came up when I googled the name of the compound plus pKa. I did not go back and check the primary sources.)

Keep in mind that both chlorine and bromine are primarily inductively electron withdrawing (-I), and to a lesser extent mesomerically electron donating (+M). Chlorine is more electronegative than bromine, so its -I effect will be more pronounced. On the other hand, chlorine's d orbitals are smaller and overlap more efficiently with the ring, giving a stronger +M effect than bromine. This, in my opinion, nicely explains all the major trends in the table:

- First, keeping the halogen constant, acidity decreases in the order ortho > meta > para, for both chloro- and bromophenols. This makes sense as the -I effect dominates and becomes weaker as the halogen atom moves further away from the hydroxyl group.
- For the ortho- and para-compounds, the acidities of the chloro- and the bromophenol are practically equal. When going from chlorine to bromine, the decreased -I effect is almost completely canceled out by the similarly decreased +M effect.
- However, meta-chlorophenol is significantly stronger than its bromo-analogue. Again what we would expect, as the mesomeric effect does not affect meta substituents, leaving only the inductive effect which is stronger in chlorine.